# Earthsea — Suggested order for Reading/Watching

Tags: suggested-order, earthsea, ursula-k-le-guin

I am wondering what books and what the suggested reading order is for the [Earthsea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea) stories by [Ursula K. Le Guin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin), and which ones have videographic adaptations (movies, miniseries, OVAs). Please also include subsidiary works (art collections, etc.) and new-for-video stories, if any.

I have read (several times) the "core three": *Wizard of Earthsea*, *The Tombs of Atuan*, and *The Farthest Shore*. This came to mind because I found an inexpensive video of a story I didn't know (Disney/Studio Ghibli's *Tales from Earthsea*)

A quick google brings up a lot of stuff that isn't Earthsea...

Comment: The Studio Ghibli *Tales from Earthsea* isn't so much a new story as a mashup of elements from all five novels, though it draws most heavily from *The Farthest Shore*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There appear to be a number of Short Stories that I haven't read as well as the 5 novels:

> The internal chronology of the stories is different from the publication order. It is, with some uncertainties:
>
> - "The Word of Unbinding"
> - "The Finder"
> - "Darkrose and Diamond"
> - "The Rule of Names" (uncertain)
> - "The Bones of the Earth"
> - **A Wizard of Earthsea**
> - **The Tombs of Atuan**
> - "On the High Marsh"
> - **The Farthest Shore**
> - **Tehanu**
> - "Dragonfly"
> - **The Other Wind**

(The novels are shown in bold type).

Lifted directly from the Wikipedia page on [Earthsea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea).

There are also details of the various adaptations for TV, Radio etc, shown on that page.

Comment: I think this list is meant to be chronological in the Earthsea series, which may or may not be a recommended literary order.

Answer (score 11):

For the stories written by Le Guin, I suggest reading in publication order, except that you can start straight with the first three or even four novels.

[ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/) has the list of [stories in the Earthsea cycle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?4220) with publication information.

- The original two short stories [*The World of Unbinding*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58853) and [*The Rule of Names*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58838), collected in [*The Wind's Twelve Quarters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37746) and others.
- The first three novels: [*A Wizard of Earthsea*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7653), [*The Tombs of Atuan*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7654), [*The Farthest Shore*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7655), telling the story of [Ged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ged_%28fictional_character%29).
- The fourth novel, [*Tehanu*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7656), furthering the story of Tenar who was the heroine of *The Tombs of Atuan*, with Ged also playing a major part.
- The short stories collected in [*Tales from Earthsea*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?39404), which provide more background on the world (some of the stories star characters met in the novels).
- The fifth novel, [*The Other Wind*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21392), a sequel to *Tehanu* and the short story *Dragonfly* also featuring Tenar, Tehanu (and Ged).

I haven't seen or heard any of the adaptations. The [Radio 4 drama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea#Radio) based on *A Wizard of Earthsea* looks decent; I recommend reading the original (the first three novels, in fact) before.
Le Guin strongly disliked both the [Sci-Fi Channel miniseries *Legend of Earthsea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_Earthsea) and the [Miyazaki film *Tales from Earthsea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_Earthsea_%28film%29), so I recommend not bothering with either (but if you do, read at least the first three novels first).